# Handle lags in Kafka S3 Connector

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We'are using Kafka Connect [distributed, confluence 4.0].

It works very well, except that there always remain an uncommitted messages in the topic that connector listens to. The behavior probably related to the  **S3 connector** configuration the `"flush.size": "20000"`. The lags in the topic are always below the flush-size.

Our data comes in batches, I don't want to wait till next batch arrive, nor reduce the `flush.size` and create tons of files.
Is there away to set timeout where S3 connector will flush the data even if it didn't reach 20000 events?

thanks!

```
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
    "topics": "event",
    "tasks.max": "3",
    "topics.dir": "connect",
    "s3.region": "some_region",
    "s3.bucket.name": "some_bucket",
    "s3.part.size": "5242880",
    "flush.size": "20000",
    "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroFormat",
    "schema.generator.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator",
    "schema.compatibility": "FULL",
    "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
    "path.format": "'\''day_ts'\''=YYYYMMdd/'\''hour_ts'\''=H",
    "partition.duration.ms": "3600000",
    "locale": "en_US",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "timestamp.extractor": "RecordField",
    "timestamp.field": "time"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flush outstanding records periodically on low-volume topics with the S3 Connector you may use the configuration property:

`rotate.schedule.interval.ms`

(Complete list of configs [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/configuration_options.html))

Keep in mind that by using the property above you might see duplicate messages in the event of reprocessing or recovery from errors, regardless of which partitioner you are using.